# Как в Yii задать id c именем страницы для body?

Tags: php, yii

Есть наверно, много способов, но как это сделать лучше всего? Кто нибудь делал вообще структуры имен страниц? Можно, наверно было бы использовать имя контроллера, например, но этого недостаточно. Контроллер один, а страницы могут быть разные. неплохо было бы прямо во вьюхе задавать имя страницы. Или в `action`. Короче, кто-нибудь так делал?

Answer (score 2):

Right way - передавать во view параметр с именем страницы. Откуда вы будете его брать - абсолютно без разницы. Из базы, из PHP, из текстового файла - вам решать.

Comment: да, очень похоже на right way

Answer (score 1):

А можно точнее о том что вообще нужно?

Если это просто страницы или статьи по разделам.

В чем проблема-то?

делаем контроллер page модель  для обработки из таблицы staticpages допустим.

в конфиге можно перенаправлять страницы сразу на view по alias от названия страницы а не по ID записи.

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'rules'=>array(
        'page/<page:\w+>'=>'page/view', 
    ),
),
```

В контроллере допустим как-нить так (это все на вскидку)

```
public function actionView()
{
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria -> select = '*';
    $criteria -> condition = 'alias=:alias';
    if (!isset($_GET['page'])) $_GET['page'] = 'main';
    $criteria -> params = array(':alias' = > $_GET['page']);
    $find_page = StaticPages::model () -> find($criteria);
    if ($find_page != NULL)
        $this -> render('view');
    else {
        $this -> breadcrumbs = array('404');
        $this -> content = '404 page not found';
        $this -> redirect('/page/404');
        $this -> render($this -> layout);
    }
}
```

Ну и все, при условии набранного адреса виде page/about лезем в бд смотрим алиас страницы если есть показываем что нужно если нет то редирект 404 или просто ошибку вывести.

Comment: да проблемы-то, может, никакой и нет. просто я только начал изучать yii, и боюсь начать применять к нему свои велосипеды. сейчас буду разбираться в вашем примере.

Comment: нет, тут речь идет не о статических страницах, а о страницах вообще. например у главной страницы id будет index, и все элементы этой страницы можно будет идентифицировать в css как #index .my_element. на странице контнактов этот элемент будет называться #contacts .my_element. это не значит, что главная страницы и страницы контактов статачны. у страниц есть id независимо от того, чем они генерируются

Comment: к каждому элементу никто не мешает добавить alias из БД - но зачем.

Comment: alias не элементу, а странице

Comment: Все с логикой в порядке?

>. на странице контактов этот элемент будет называться #contacts .my_element. 

А дальше ты пишешь обратное

>alias не элементу, а странице

Я тебя не понимать вообще. Разберись в голове что нужно а что нет, и как это должно быть.

и прими ответы на свои вопросы!